# How to Print PCF Fresh logs in console in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pcf

[PCF Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sjj1.png)

[Inspect Element -> Pcf Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naCjj.png)

[Pcf Fresh Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4cga.png)

In Selenium, I need to capture the fresh logs in PCF. Once you click the Pause log button, fresh logs will be come. I just need the fresh logs, no old logs should be come.

**Below code I tried ,click the Pause log button i.e, icon-play_arrow .once the Play button stated I am taking the xpath of the logs afterwards I am able to capture the full logs**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='icon-play_arrow']")).click();

List<WebElement> logs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//main[@id='main-content']"));

String timestamp = 
        new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'h:mm:ss a").format(new Date());
System.out.println(timestamp);
System.out.println(logs.size());
for (WebElement webElement : logs) {
    String pcflogs = webElement.getText();
    System.out.println(pcflogs);
}
```

As you can see the fresh logs are coming like:

> 2020-01-09T01:52:19.715+05:30 [RTR/1] [OUT] runautomationproject-org.cfapps.io - [2020-01-08T20:22:19.705907829Z] "OPTIONS /cloudfoundryapplication HTTP/1.1" 403 0 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36" "10.10.66.133:27358" "10.10.148.128:61258" x_forwarded_for:"1.22.151.131, 10.10.66.133" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"fb05f272-ef20-410e-5c20-e7252653f4d5" response_time:0.009504 gorouter_time:0.000086 app_time:0.009418 app_id:"4b70548e-3348-456a-911f-38fd7e9f83d6" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"3a3dd693065a522e" x_b3_spanid:"3a3dd693065a522e" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"3a3dd693065a522e-3a3dd693065a522e"
>
> 2020-01-09T02:12:26.477+05:30 [RTR/2] [OUT] runautomationproject-org.cfapps.io - [2020-01-08T20:42:26.466794812Z] "OPTIONS /cloudfoundryapplication HTTP/1.1" 403 0 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36" "10.10.66.133:53138" "10.10.148.128:61258" x_forwarded_for:"1.22.151.131, 10.10.66.133" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"85478596-81eb-4a71-6ade-5fe5b352b5bf" response_time:0.010881 gorouter_time:0.000087 app_time:0.010794 app_id:"4b70548e-3348-456a-911f-38fd7e9f83d6" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"16a9ac1495aad284" x_b3_spanid:"16a9ac1495aad284" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"16a9ac1495aad284-16a9ac1495aad284"

If I set this in below format also, it's not able to detect in Logs.

```
String timestamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'h:mm:ss a").format(new Date());
```

Please help :)